# How to use one outputstream to return multiple data?

Tags: java, jaxb, outputstream, dataoutputstream

I want to return two distinct data using one outputStream in java.

I want to return xml response and download a file.

I am using JAXB to write my xml response,

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(request.getResponseStream());
JAXBContext newInstance = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetCoverageType.class);
Marshaller marshaller = newInstance.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(responseData.getCoverage(), dos);

File file = new File(responseData.getLocation());
response.addHeader("ContentDisposition", "attachment; filename=test");
response.setContentType("application/netcdf");
Files.copy(file, dos);
```

With my code, the file is downloaded but the xml generated by JAXB does not appear.

I have tried to use `response.flushBuffer()` after that, but the xml response is written in my downloaded file.

If someone has an idea to download my file and return xml response on the browser

Thanks

Comment: Use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use its array twice

Comment: Can you show me an example to how instanciate it ?

Comment: I was thinking of using header location to send an other request with one parameter to tell if i want my file or my xml